# 2D Array [object, object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I have a 2d array going on in the example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/v0019po127

I am getting mixed results depending on console log being used i.e. browser or codesandbox

I have tried json.stringify also to sole issue.

When I select "no" from the table it outputs to my value as below image:

[image]

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(value)) //returns [["","",""],["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]
```

My end goal is to return this(slowly getting there):

```
value = [
{ personId: "0003678", seniorStatus: "Yes", juniors: "maybe" },
{ personId: "0001657", seniorStatus: "No", juniors: "No" },
{ personId: "0002345", seniorStatus: "No", juniors: "No", infants: "Maybe" }]
```

Where it adds the personId and associated selection for that person to a new array.

If anybody can help achieve this from my demo it would be such a relief as its been worked on for awhile now. please!

Comment: Do you want the result to have all the initial rows or just the one you answer with button clicks?

Comment: I do not know anything about `react`, but putting a log into `handleValue` shows that `cellIdx` happens to be an object, like `{label: "Seniors", value: "Seniors"}`. That is not a really good index for a 3-element array which may be a starting point to explain why it does not work.

Comment: @0xc14m1z Not fussed really - it would work either way

Comment: And is it possible to enhance your data structures to fulfill your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code and created a Sandbox for the same.

The 'cellIdx' you are passing have 2 elements i.e. label and value. So, you should only pass either a label or a value to handleValue function.

Here is the link.
[https://codesandbox.io/s/2135o51k20][1]

Comment: Such minor amends! I was not too far off really. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help :)